# If my buffered reader is reading a line greater than 2 Mb, will it buffer the line or will the buffer size increase?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I know that the default buffer size is 2 Mb, and that's what I'm working with.

Comment: What tells you that that is the default?

Comment: Last time I checked, the default buffer size of `BufferedReader` was 8192 chars (Java 6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. The size of the buffer doesn't change the external behavior of the stream (except indirectly, in terms of how often it will read from the underlying stream). If you try to `read` more data than is in the buffer, it will drain the buffer and then read the rest directly from the underlying stream. If you `readLine` and the newline isn't contained within the buffer, it will do the same thing, copying data to the output until it *does* find the newline, but without any effect on the size of the stream's own buffer.

Incidentally, the default buffer size isn't 2MB in any implementation I've spotted; classpath uses 8kB, and Oracle seems to use 4kB or 8kB.

Answer (score 0):

It uses an internal `StringBuffer` to hold the line assembled so far, which grows as much as necessary. It doesn't grow the read buffer.

Answer (score -2):

BufferedReader is not necessarily line oriented. It will read 2Mb (if that is the size of the buffer) in any case.